# Confirming whether an email exists or not

Tags: django, smtp, email-validation

There are similar questions and I have already basically checked all of them. My question is when I try to clarify whether an e-mail really exists or not(such as test@test.com, I cannot clarify the same with my company email.

The package I have used is py3-validate-email. Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I should do as the next step?

I know that this tool checks for the regex as well, I have copied the code to receive any opinion.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader 
from django.http import Http404

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
import re

from validate_email import validate_email

def validate_email_address(email_address):

   return re.search(r"^[A-Za-z0-9_!#$%&'*+\/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$", email_address)

def contact_func(request, ):
    template = loader.get_template("contact_page/contact_page.html")
    context = {
        "contact":"contact_us",
        }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST['message']
        email = request.POST['email']
        name = request.POST['name']


        if not validate_email_address(email):
            return HttpResponse("Invalid email address")

        is_valid = validate_email(
        email_address= email, 
        check_format=True,
        check_blacklist=True,
        check_dns=True,
        dns_timeout=10,
        check_smtp=True,
        smtp_timeout=10,
        smtp_helo_host='smtp.gmail.com',
        smtp_from_address='my_mail.com',
        smtp_skip_tls=False,
        smtp_tls_context=None,
        smtp_debug=False,
    )

        if not is_valid:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid email address")




        send_mail(
            name, #title
            message + '\nsend by ' + email,
            request.POST['email'],
            ['my_mail.com'], #receiver email
            fail_silently=False, 
        )

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: The most common way to validate an email address is to send an email to the user supplied email address and have them click a link that validates that the address exists and the user has access to it. What are you using the package "py3-validate-email" for? After checking the package and the license it uses I would think twice before using it too

Comment: @IainShelvington, first of all, thank you for the return, I think there has been a slight misunderstanding, The client is not signing in or logging in to my website. It simply wants to fill this "contact us" form and send me an e-mail. But I need to validate whether this e-mail exists, do you think the same approach you have described above is still valid or is there a really another way to validate the e-mail ? such as verifying the client mail's sever like VRFY command. I am not sure the other server will support this command ?

Comment: For a "contact us" form I think that sending confirmation to the supplied email address after submission (and informing the user that this will happen) is enough in the majority of cases. If you must verify that the email address exists I would urge you to use a different package, "py3-validate-email" was removed from PyPI because it's license is fairly unsavoury and more than a little controversial